# outer div height not expanding with img inside

Tags: html, css, image

I have a structure like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="cat_item">
    <div class="cat_image">
         <img src="/res/imyg/srm450v2.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="cat_desc">
        <h2>Mackie - SRM450v2</h2>
        <p>
             Description Text
        </p>
     </div>
</div>
```

**LESS**

```
.cat_item {
  padding:10px;
  border-radius:5px;
  background-color:white;

  box-shadow:2px 2px 5px black;

  color:black;

  .cat_image {
    float:left;

    margin-right:25px;
    padding:5px;

    background-color:red;

    img {
      width:125px;
      height:175px;
    }
  }

  .cat_desc {
    padding:5px;
  }
}
```

Now I want the cat_item div to be changing height, so it fits the image. However only the text influences the height of cat_item div. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yes I am using LessCSS. Otherwise my code is no valid CSS.

Comment: look at the this pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zJhws. 
I used:
.cat_image img {
  width: 200px;
}

Comment: You removed the float:left; which rendered my approach completely useless, because the picture is no longer to the left of the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the float. Try a clearfix CSS or set overflow: hidden to the outer div.

> How to clear CSS floats without extra markup – different techniques
>   explained. There are three major approaches: a) Floating the
>   containing element as well, b) Using `overflow: hidden` on the container, c) Generating content using the `:after` CSS
>   pseudo-class.

From: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/01/css-float-theory-things-you-should-know/

Comment: If I set overflow:hidden to the outer div, it won't change size but instead parts of the image would just be invisible, wouldn't they? That isn't really what I want to achieve.

Comment: Just try it out. It shouldn't.

Comment: Yes overflow:hidden; is exactly what I meant. But now I feel like I am going to be confused with CSS for like the rest of my life. Can you explain why this overflow:hidden; changes the behaviour of the height, instead of doing what I though it would do?

Answer (score 0):

You need the following just before the last closing `</div>`.

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

And in your CSS:

```
.clearfix{
    clear: both;
}
```